# Protection of rows within an edition allowed range conditional to data entry in a column

Tags: vba, excel

Good afternoon,
I have a worksheet protected with a password where users are allowed to edit only the range comprised by the cells `C19:G23` and `C32:L70`.
I need to create a VBA that verifies if data was input in any of the rows in column C within the range above, write the word "Ok" in column B of the rows where data was input and protects these for further edition. In other words, I need to modify/overwrite the edition allowed range based on data input in column C.
I tried several ways over 2 the last days, including the private sub below taken from another answer found here with several modifications, but none of them worked.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim mypassword As String, StringToCheck As String

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Change the password here to protect/unprotect the sheet
    mypassword = "Maze"

    '~~> Change it to the relevant string with which you want to compare
    StringToCheck = "Ok"

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C70")) Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Check for the cell value
        If Target.Value = “Ok” Then
            '~~> Un-Protect the sheet
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect Squonk

            '~~> Lock the cell
            Range("A1:AAA50000").Locked = True

            '~~> Re-Protect the sheet
            ActiveSheet.Protect Squonk
        End If
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand the protection part of your question, but the rest *(I need to create a VBA that verifies if data was input in any of the rows in column C within the range above, write the word "Ok" in column B of the rows where data was input)* should be done through this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C70")) Is Nothing And _
        Intersect(Target, Range("C19:G23")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Cells(Target.Row, 2) = "OK"

End Sub
```

The trick is to exit the sub on 3 condtions:

- More than one cell
- Target outside C1:C70
- Target outside C19:G23

Then use the property `.Row` of `Target` in order to write the "OK" on column "B".

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer, Vitaya. I'll try to explain furhter.

Comment: @Haellion - the locking and the unlocking part should be easily done once you know what to do.

Comment: There is a resource on Excel called "Allow Users to Edit Ranges" found on the "Review" tab under the "Changes" section (Excel 2016). It allows to protect the whole sheet but leaving a range for edition under the protection of a second password. This is my range (C19:G23 and C32:L70). I tried this code before but it doesn't work too. Also, I realized that I need to trigger it with a button to let the users to edit the rest of the range and not only the column C. Is there any way to do it with a public sub?

Comment: @Haellion - simply record a macro while doing it.

Comment: Vityata, I tried that but then I'll have to recreate 1 macro for every line and make a button for every macro. It would be very cumbersome, not to mention that the users won't be able to use more than 1 line at the time. I need to be able to edit as many lines as I want within the range and then hit the button to action the macro because these lines will be added up and exported to another sheet creating another document based on the lack of "Ok" on column B.

Comment: @Haellion - try to edit the recorded macro code so it works for every line.

Comment: I tried already. Apparently I'm not capable of. Do you know how to change a range based on if a cell has a content or not?

Comment: @Haellion - google **how to change a range based on if a cell has a content or not** and see the first 20 results.

Comment: I though it could work but the range set in the "Allow Users to Edit Ranges" cannot be changed the same way an ordinary range, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this below sowing from a bunch a found and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much for the help!

```
Sub Test()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Maze"
Dim mainworkBook As Workbook
Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range
lastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In Range("C32:C70" & lastRow)
If InStr(1, cell.Value, "") <> 0 Then
cell.Offset(, -1).Value = "Ok"
End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Maze"
End Sub
```